# Perl exporting module function from higher directory

Tags: perl, module, perl-module

I have file .../module.pm and file .../somedir/program.pl
How to export function from module.pm to program.pl? Or how to get path to current script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `use FindBin` to retrieve the path of the current script:

```
use FindBin;  # locate this script
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../module.pm";  # use the parent directory
use yourlib;
```